# Adding complex exponential in Fourier coefficients

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I understand the following Euler trigonometric identities:

$$sin(\omega t)=\frac{e^{j\omega t}-e^{-j\omega t}}{2j}$$

and

$$e^{j\omega t}-e^{-j\omega t} = 2jsin(\omega t)$$

What I dont understand is how $-3je^{j\omega t}+3je^{-j\omega t} =6\left [\frac{e^{j\omega t}-e^{-j\omega t}}{2j} \right ]$

This is regarding Fourier Series coefficients where $\pm 3J$ are the coefficients. I'm using the above concepts and the answer should be $6sin(\omega t)$, however the use of the complex number J is confusing me. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Hi: factor out +3 from the LHS of the. expression. Then you'll be left with $(2 \times 3)  j sin(\omega t)$.

Comment: They use $j=-\frac 1j$